# Problems running ghost with docker in development

Tags: docker, ghost

I'm having a hard time running a container from the Ghost image in development (after `docker pull ghost`).

Using:

```
docker run --name some-ghost -p 4000:2368 -v /Users/Documents/ghost-blog/content/themes/:/var/lib/ghost/content/themes/ -e NODE_ENV=development ghost
```

seems to start the container in development but when I navigate to the page in browser I get

> localhost didn’t send any data. ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

I've tried looking this up but it seems like development was previously the default environment until recently. I'm not really sure where to proceed.

Comment: Are you using `docker-machine`? Are you using the right port in the URL (4000)?

Comment: I'm not. I'm fairly new to docker, I'm not sure what `docker-machine` is. Yes I'm using the correct port. When I switch to production the URL works as intended.

Comment: Try visiting `http://localhost:4000`.

Comment: Doesn't work in dev, getting the error above. It works in production though.

Comment: I tried running that, it works normally with production env as you said, but it returns a `HTTP 500 Internal Server Error` with development env. But that is an error with Ghost. However it sends back a response.   Running the container, does it echo an error?

Comment: There's no error in the container, I get `Ghost is running in development`. I'm not getting a server error either it's `324`.

Comment: I am seeing the same issue. Works in production mode, but not in development. Have you found a solution yet?

Answer (score 0):

According to [acburdine's answer](https://github.com/docker-library/ghost/issues/88#issuecomment-327135262), you need to specify further environment variables:

`docker run --name some-ghost -p 4000:2368 -v /Users/Documents/ghost-blog/content/themes/:/var/lib/ghost/content/themes/ -e NODE_ENV=development -e server__host=0.0.0.0 -e url="http://localhost:2368" ghost`